# Пошаговая HTML форма без потерь

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, form

Как реализовать пошаговую форму, которая на каждом шаге будет захватывать уже указанные данные? Например:
Шаг 1: укажите емейл, кнопка ОК. По нажатию ОК появляется следующий шаг
Шаг 2: укажите имя, кнопка ОК. и т.д.
Хотелось бы сохранять данные каждого шага без потерь, сколько бы шагов не прошел пользователь.
Спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Для хранения данных, можно использовать cookie, а можно localStorage или sessionStorage. Среди ночи уже нет сил на оптимизацию, посему пардоньте, за "кучу" кода. В песочнице SO выполняться отказывается, поэтому [рабочий пример на jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7eparndz/2/). После заполнения формы, если не нажмёте кнопку "Finish", можете перезагрузить страницу, закрыть окно, открыть ссылку снова. Данные и позиция формы останутся в последнем её состоянии.

```
<div id="form-output">
    <form>
        <div>
            <p>
                <input name="inp1" type="text">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input name="inp2" type="text">
            </p>
            <p>
                <select name="opt1">
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="a">A</option>
                    <option value="b">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <input name="inp3" type="text">
            </p>
            <p>
                <input name="inp4" type="text">
            </p>
            <p>
                <select name="opt2">
                    <option></option>
                    <option value="a">A</option>
                    <option value="b">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                </select>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Finish">
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="control-panel">
        <button>&lt;</button>
        <button>&gt;</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var ctrl = $('#control-panel button'),
    output = $('#form-output'),
    form = $('form', output),
    formElems = $(':text, select', form),
    step = output.outerWidth(),
    maxPos = form.width() - step,
    pos, dir,
    ls = {
        set: function() {
            // Сохраняем данные формы и её координаты
            var data = {
                form: form.attr('style'),
                vals: {}
            };
            formElems.each(function(i, el) {
                data.vals[$(el).attr('name')] = $(el).val();
            });
            localStorage.setItem('myform', JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        get: function() {
            var data = localStorage.getItem('myform');
            // Если в LS есть данные, то подставляем в элементы формы
            if (data) {
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                $.each(data.vals, function(name, val) {
                    formElems.filter('[name=' + name + ']').val(val);
                });
                form.attr('style', data.form);
            }
        },
        clear: function(e) {
            // Удаляем данные из LS
            localStorage.removeItem('myform');
            // Если нужно отменить обычную отправку данных
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).animate({
                left: 0
            })[0].reset();
        }
    };
ls.get();
ctrl.on('click', function() {
    pos = Math.abs(form.position().left);
    dir = ctrl.index(this);
    if (pos > maxPos && dir || pos <= 0 && !dir) {
        return false;
    }
    // После завершения анимации, записываем данные формы в LS
    form.animate({
        left: '-=' + (ctrl.index(this) ? step : -step)
    }, ls.set);
});
// После отправки формы, данные в LS очищаются
form.on('submit', ls.clear);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если под "без потерь" имеется ввиду без перезагрузки страницы то, мне кажется что  вполне адекватными являются следующие варианты:

1. Сделать так, чтобы по прошествии очереднего шага пряталась текущая форма и на ее месте появлялась другая. Т.е храним некие шаблоны и тасуем их.
2. Или ничего не тасовать а менять данные в текущей форме на лету.
   Брать данные с сервера и генерировать форму на основе данных

Данные с каждого шага упаковывать в объект и в завершении отправлять его на сервер.

Comment: Так же данные можно хранить в JS-переменных, а потом отправлять всё вместе. Либо можно сделать одну форму, но при нажатии кнопки "ок" скрывать блоки с полями формы. Вариантов на самом деле масса. :)

Comment: @intro94, вариантов масса. Да. Правда на счет переменных я не понял. Имеем n полей, не создавать же на них переменные? Сразу в объект их паковать.

Comment: Можно в массив записывать. Можно написать скрипт, который не будет привязан к конкретной форме, а сможет работать с любой динамической формой, данные сохранять будет в виде массива, а потом этот массив отправлять на сервер. В общем, вариантов много. :)